# Checking two lists of tuples for same first value

Tags: python-2.7, list, tuples

How do I check two lists of tuples for the same first value?

```
list1=[(1,3),(3,2),(5,-5),(7,7)]
list2=[(1,-2),(2,2),(4,8),(5,6)]
```

I want to add `list1[i][1] to list2[y][1] if list1[i][0] is = list2[y][0]`

so for the example list that would be the case for

```
(1,3) and (1,-2)
and
(5,-5) and (5,6)
```

it should add 3+(-2) and -5+6

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to re-invent dictionaries, so why not just using them? It would greatly improve the lookup time

```
dict1 = dict(list1)
dict2 = dict(list2)

result = {k1: v1 + dict2.get(k1, 0) for k1, v1 in dict1.iteritems()}
```

but if you really want to go with lists:

```
for i, (i0, i1) in enumerate(list1):
    for y0, y1 in list2:
        if i0 == y0:
            list1[i][1] += y1
```

Comment: getting an error TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignmentworks 
but otherwise works perfectly thanks